# How to pass custom material input data to a certain GBuffer channel in UnrealEngine4 and 5?

Tags: render, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

The problem had struck me 7 days .

I've been reading the [commit](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/pull/2476) here . I've noticed it mentioned names '*NUM_MATERIAL_OUTPUTS_CUSTOMBUFFEROUTPUT*'and '*CustomBufferOutput0*' . It's quite strange to me , as I can't find them be mentioned in all other usf files . I guess they are user-defined , but what made me confused is that it seems no other file is absent , other than the header file of the new custom node named '*MaterialExpressionCustomBufferOutput*'  , which has been fixed in conversation and basically a duplicate of MaterialExpressionCustomOutput .

However I believe there's something in common on the word 'Buffer' that appeared at the same time in both the names '*NUM_MATERIAL_OUTPUTS_CUSTOMBUFFEROUTPUT*'and '*CustomBufferOutput0*' . It was how he defined the new node with the name *UMaterialExpressionCustomBufferOutput* . So 'Buffer' = custom . I think there might be some auto program that had generated corresponding variable and function . But I can't find any documents about it , so I'm not sure . I can't understand how he passed the input of the node to GBuffer . I guess *CustomBufferOutput0(MaterialParameters);* reads the data written by *Compiler->CustomOutput(this, OutputIndex, Input.Compile(Compiler, MultiplexIndex));* . If anyone can help , I'd be very grateful .